# How to make sure that predictions follow the distribution of the target, which can't be transformed into a normal distribution

Tags: machine-learning, prediction

In this regression problem, target has peaks at certain points. For example, there are many samples with target values 3 and 5 than 4. Please refer the snip below.

[image]

I want to still treat it as a regression problem and be quite close for those peak point predictions. The dataset also has many categorical variables and missing values. Using the boosting and bagging algorithms give out small MAE but the distribution of these predictions is normal. While I am looking at something which can give out somewhat close distribution to the target, mainly not concentrating the mid ranges where original target don't have many samples.
Are there any algorithms that can help me achieve this? I have tried to transform the target with sqrt but that doesn't work due to the nature of target.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to modify the sampling method; the sample should be **shuffled** and represents the population of your data.
I need more detail on your problem to provide a clear solution.
For the transformation using the sqrt, I don't know if it would help, but I guess you can't do it directly because you have negative elements in the target, if so you can transform the target by adding to it the -minimum value of your target then use sqrt.